# How I can create complicated logic that use CurrentUser variable or value from field of the object on ListView filter?

Tags: list-view, lightninglistview

The main issue is How I can use fields from object inclusive related fields.
For example : On any Custom Object : [image]

Comment: Create a formulae field with the condition for running user and refer it in the list view filter.

Comment: Thanks H Reddy, but if I need to create a lot of filters that need to use relation fields ? Then I will have to create a lot of fields on the object ( 
Maybe there is a better way to solve this problem other than creating Custom component or field on the object ??

Comment: Checkbox formula field on the object `Is_CreatedBy_Me` defined as `CreatedById = $User.Id` -- or, a text formula field on the object `Me__c` defined as `$User.Id`that you reference in the Value field of your filter